# Using catch blocks to produce error messages

Tags: java, exception, return, throw

How would i get the NumberFormatException catch block to produce the first line of the error message and the second line from the call to the getMessage method

the message should look something like this when the input file has invalid data entered

**** input file format error ****

For input string: "non-numeric"

here is my  AcademicWarning program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class AcademicWarning
{
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  // Read student data (name, semester hours, quality points) from
  // a text file, compute the GPA, then write data to another file
  // if the student is placed on academic warning
  // -------------------------------------------------------------
  public static void main(String[] args)    
  {
    DecimalFormat two_digits = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
    Scanner            input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input_file_name;
    String output_file_name;

    int    credit_hours;    // Number of semester hours earned
    double quality_points;  // Number of quality points earned
    double gpa;             // Grade point (quality point) average
    String student_name;

    System.out.print("Input file name: ");
    input_file_name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Output file name: ");
    output_file_name = input.nextLine();

    try
    {
      Scanner      input_file = new Scanner(new File(input_file_name));
      PrintWriter output_file = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(output_file_name));

      // ---------------------------------
      // Print a header to the output file
      // ---------------------------------
      output_file.println();
      output_file.println("Students on Academic Warning");
      output_file.println();

      // ------------------------------------------
      // Process the input file one token at a time
      // ------------------------------------------
      while (input_file.hasNext())
      {
        // ---------------------------------------
        // Get the credit hours and quality points
        // and if the student is on warning write
        // the student data to the output file
        // ---------------------------------------
        student_name   = input_file.next();
        credit_hours   = Integer.parseInt(input_file.next());
        quality_points = Double.parseDouble(input_file.next());
        gpa            = quality_points / credit_hours;
        if (gpa < 2.00)
          output_file.println(student_name + " " + credit_hours + " " +
                              two_digits.format(gpa));
      }
      output_file.close();
    }

    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
      System.out.println(nfe.getMessage());
    }

    catch(FileNotFoundException fnf)
    {
      System.out.println(fnf.getMessage());
    }

    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
      System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: You're doing the same thing in each catch block. Why not replace it with a single catch block like so: `catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage());`

Comment: If i could make it that easy I would. But I am trying to produce the necessary output for a school assignment where you have to strictly follow specification given by the teacher @Mage Xy

Answer (score 0):

Add `NUMERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE` like in this example:

```
public class AcademicWarning
{
  private static final String NUMERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE = "**** input file format error ****";
```

Then on your catch block:

```
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
  System.out.println(String.format("%s%n%s", NUMERIC_ERROR_MESSAGE, nfe.getMessage());
}
```

This will print the required error header + a line break (\n) + the message from the exception.